# Does the diagonalization formula of a non-diagonal matrix have any derivation or origin?

Tags: matrices, diagonalization

I am referring to the method of diagonalization in order to transform a matrix $ A $ into $ D $ using the formula $ \\ D = MAM^{-1} \\ $ where $ D $ is the diagonal matrix constructed using the eigenvalues of $ A $ as the main diagonal in an arbitrarily selected order, $ M $ is the modal matrix where each column is the eigenvector of the corresponding column in the diagonal matrix and $ A $ is the selected matrix.

Is there like a derivation of where it came from? I've stumbled upon multiple textbooks and they don't really explain where it came from but they do establish why it works.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "where it came from"? Are you asking for historical context?

Comment: There are many decompositions which have all their use cases, LU, QR, the polar QP, the SVD $U\Sigma V^*$ etc. Conjugation corresponds to a base change for an endomorphism, one can always ask for a base change with "the most zeros".

Comment: I am not asking for historical context but pretty much I want a sorts of derivation just like how most formulas are derived from other formulas or have a concept behind them. Like take for example, the derivation behind the characteristic polynomial \\ A - \lambda I \\. I want to be able to remember the concept without having to memorize it and knowing the derivation helps. I mean even if it is complicated, I haven't read anything at all that establishes where it came from that doesn't just throw the concepts at me.